# Does rel="home" on an anchor tag (<a>) do anything helpful?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup, wcag, microformats

I see this a lot on site title links in WordPress themes (probably because Underscores does it and everyone copies that):

```html
<a href="/" rel="home">Some Site Title</a>
```

I cannot find even a semi-authoritative statement anywhere that `rel="home"` on an anchor tag is *used* meaningfully today by any browser, screen reader, or other user agent. The only "official" documentation I've located is [this draft specification from 2005](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-home) on the microformats.org site.

That doc proposes `home` as a valid value on both `<link>` tags in the `<head>`, as well as `<a>` tags. Using it on a `<link>` has some [pedigree from HTML v3](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/dochead.html), and there's [reference to it in the wild](https://web.archive.org/web/20080813033016/http://diveintoaccessibility.org/day_9_providing_additional_navigation_aids.html) from 2002. But I haven't seen anything about the `<a>` tag usage.

So, is including it helpful for anything/anyone? Would I do better to use `<link rel="home">` in the `<head>`, or is that obsolete too in 2020?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rel="page"` was part of an initiative to create [permalinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink) (see section 'Permalink detection') as part of a standard in HTML 4.

However with HTML 5 it now has no purpose and does not offer any accessibility or SEO value. It also might not validate using W3C validator anymore (not tested).

`rel="something"` should only be used on `<link>` elements, with the exception of `rel="noopener"`, `rel="nofollow"` or `rel="noreferrer"` on anchors (`<a>` tags).

**Note** - There may be other `rel=""` for hyperlinks but the two stated are the only ones I can think of, it is no longer valid to use it for page locations, bookmarks etc.

### Update

Thanks to @Sean who pointed out in the comments [other elements can accept `rel=""`](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions), however [MicroFormats](http://microformats.org/wiki/Main_Page) are not the preferred way of adding structured data according to Google and their development is not as full fledged as using https://schema.org and `JSON+LD`.

> “We currently prefer JSON-LD markup. I think most of the new
>   structured data come out for JSON-LD first. So that’s
>   what we prefer.” - **John Mueller**

I am obviously incorrect in what I said as it is perfectly valid, however personally I would not bother and stick with what Google prefers apart from the few items I listed.

See @Sean's answer for a bit more info on the subject.

**for clarity `rel=""` has no bearing on accessibility**

Comment: On a whim I just ran it through the W3C [nu validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/), and interestingly it seems to ignore `rel` entirely — not only did "home" and "asdf" raise no complaints, but sticking `rel` on other random tags (body, script, title) wasn't flagged either.

There's a nice table of [defined link types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) (all the "good" `rel` values) on MDN. Quite a few are allowed on anchors, actually.

Comment: Thanks @Andron, always great to learn something new. I suppose it is a valid attribute on anything, just won't serve any meaningful purpose, I should probably brush up on my knowledge on what it is allowed for other than the few recommended uses (obviously hadn't thought of things like `next`, `prev` etc!)

Answer (score 2):

`home` isn't one of the [allowed keywords](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#linkTypes) explicitly defined by the current [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) as allowed values for the `rel` attribute. However, the spec goes on to state that:

> Types defined as extensions in the [microformats wiki existing-rel-values page](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions) with the status "proposed" or "ratified" may be used with the `rel` attribute on `link`, `a`, and `area` elements in accordance to the "Effect on..." field.

On that [microformats page](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#linkTypes), `home` has the "proposed" status—so it is valid to use according to the spec.

There's a specific [`rel-home`](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-home) page within that microformats site that goes into more detail about the usage with examples. It makes the statement—

> Opera browser supports rel="home"

—which would imply that Opera has some functionality tied to that usage, but it doesn't provide any additional details.

**Summary:** `rel="home"` is valid to use on `a` elements. It's benefits aren't clear, but it doesn't hurt to use it. The [draft spec](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-home) for it has been around since 2005, so there's bound to be some technologies that make use of it.